# Combining several fields using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to combine several table fields in order to produce a combined value.

Here's my code:

```
from _showtime in db.tbl_Concert_Showtime join _concerthall in db.tbl_Concert_ConcertHall on _showtime.ConcertHallID equals _concerthall.ConcertHallID
                 join _hall in db.tbl_Concert_Hall on _concerthall.HallID equals _hall.HallID
                 join _hallfloor in db.tbl_Concert_Hall_Floor on _hall.HallID equals _hallfloor.HallID
                 join _place in db.tbl_Concert_Hall_Floor_Place on _hallfloor.FloorID equals _place.FloorID
                 where _place.PlaceID == id
                 select _showtime
```

The `showtime` table includes the `showID`, `startdate`, `starttime` and `endtime` fields.

How can I select `startdate` and `starttime` in a field?

Something like this: `2015/12/12 12:25 -> 12:58`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from _showtime in db.tbl_blablabla    
select _showtime.startdate + " " + _showtime.starttime + " -> " + _showtime.enddate
```

If you wanna Keep your original Showtime object but just add that combined value, do something like the follwoing:

```
from _showtime in db.tbl_blablabla    
select new 
{
    Showtime = _Showtime, 
    CombinedValue = _showtime.startdate + " " + _showtime.starttime + " -> " + _showtime.enddate
}
```

Comment: How to chose the name of the new field? like showID and NewSeveral field

Comment: What do you mean by name in this context? The result will just be one or more strings.

Comment: I'd like to show the result in drop down list. I need a showID filed for value and  NewSeveral (_showtime.startdate + " " + _showtime.starttime + " -> " + _showtime.enddate) for display